# High level SDK for Facebook .NET

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Just started reading and learning how to use Facebook SDK for .NET.

It seems there is a use of dynamic object almost everywhere.

I can't see any reasons why this should not be wrapped up with some nicely strongly-typed C#-like library.

A library that already knows all the datatypes that Facebook Graph might return,
and allows strongly-typed access to these, via properties.

Instead of the (in my eyes) horrible dynamic objects.

I couldn't find anything like this.

Does anyone know anything like this? Or did I missunderstand something, that make this impossible, or unimportant?

**EDIT:**

I'm aware of stuff like this:

https://gist.github.com/ntotten/906471

```
  var fb = new FacebookClient("access_token");
  var result = fb.Get<FBUser>("/me");
  string name = result.Name;


  public class FBUser {
     [DataMember(Name="name")]
     public string Name { get; set; }
     [DataMember(Name="first_name")]
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
  }
```

But I couldn't find a library that contains all these datatypes ready to use.

We are all interfacing to the same Facebook API... I assume it's not reasonable everyone will rewrite the same classes.